# When can I tune in to Vicki Vale's broadcasts?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I love soaking up the ambiance in Arkham city. As an eavesdropper, I usually listen in on every henchman dialogue I can find. Vicki Vale occasionally broadcasts on Gotham FM which you can listen to using the cryptographic sequencer. She can also be heard from a radio in the church when you rescue the medical personnel from the henchmen. During the course of the game, when can I tune in to listen to her updates regarding Arkham city, using the sequencer or another radio?

Answer (score 1):

No particular time, unfortunately.

Outside of the timers on certain objectives, there's just simply no concept of time in Arkham City. Vicki Vale and other broadcasts are just like the random banter of henchmen -- no connection to anything, really, just more-or-less random ambiance to deepen your immersion. (Ironically, that realization destroyed my immersion...)

If you stay tuned in long enough, and especially if you don't advance the main plot, you will start to hear good ol' Vicki repeat herself; conversely, tune in right after accomplishing major objectives, and you'll often (but not always) hear her talking about your most recent exploits.

Comment: So Vicki Vale is on some sort of timer in between the songs being played on Gotham FM?  I thought it was specifically tied to completion of objectives. At least the objectives seem to trigger new dialogue. How long is the interval between broadcasts?

Comment: Can't say I've timed it. It could even be somewhat random, like the chatter among henchmen. There definitely are broadcasts tied to the completion of major objectives though; your best bet is probably to tune in immediately after completing an objective if you don't want to miss any important broadcast, and/or you can just chill and listen to the radio for a while as you look out over the city from some secure perch.